# Installing xlsx package in R

Tags: r, package, xlsx

I am trying to install xlsx via CRAN for R.

```
install.packages("xslx")

# Warning message:
# package 'xlsx' is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

Does this mean I need to get an older version of R?

OS X Yosemite 10.10
R 3.1.2 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build

Thanks!

Comment: You do have to spell it correctly...

Comment: well thats embarrassing. thanks